# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 Server : No runtime environment deployed in this server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Successfully installed IBM MobileFirst 7.0 Server on following environment, and also, a runtime environment was created step by step and deployed `successfully` in this server (with *GUI* of MobileFirst Platform Configurion Tool shows **deployed**):

- CentOS 6.4
- MobileFirst Server 7.0
- jdk-7u79
- MySQL 5.6.24
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.62

But I got a `No runtime environment deployed in this server` from worklightconsole.

I can't find any logs show the error messages. Also,the `WL` related tables was created automatically in MySQL databases and Worklight related folder generated in Tomcat path, too.

[image: No runtime environment deployed in this server]
[image: Database connected and table generated successfully]
[image: Tomcat configure]

The *GUI* of MobileFirst Platform Configurion Tool shows **deployed**:
[image: *GUI* of MobileFirst Platform Configurion Tool shows **deployed**]

Comment: Find the messages.log in your Tomcat logs folder. Provide it.

Comment: @IdanAdar  You mean catalina.2015-06-01.log or localhost.2015-06-01.log ?

Comment: I mean the systemout.log I think

Comment: @IdanAdar the whole `tomcat\logs` folder uploaded. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w33ndt7tf9hjtac/AABDfpsScrvCFBwh07-4YIKWa?dl=0

Comment: @IdanAdar `systemout.log` not found in any log folders...

Comment: @Sam as i have found the _<openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException:_ this may happen because of dying connection with Databases. I hope you have tried [Tomcat Dying database connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949/javatomcat-dying-database-connection).

Comment: @Sam does it happens every time? How you tried restarting the server instance, I hope its not production.

Comment: @dhineshsundar have restarted Tomcat for more than 10 time but still not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause to the failure may be due to an ssoExpiredLoginContextsCleanupTask error which can cause the server to not load:

> Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: Cannot
>   execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since
>   BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine
>   limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when
>   transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.
>   {prepstmnt 1015602967 INSERT INTO CLUSTER_SYNC (ID, hostVmId,
>   updateTimestamp, version) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) [params=(String)
>   ssoExpiredLoginContextsCleanupTask, (null) null, (long) 0, (long) 0]}
>   [code=1665, state=HY000]

To correct it, it is suggested to follow these instructions: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21695572, which are also relevant to MFP Server (and not just Application Center Server).

Comment: THX u, buddy. Finally this was solved by using another MySQL server.