# JPA application doesn't return from call to JPA repository after running for many hours

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an application in development using spring boot jpa with a mysql db all on windows 10.

The application usually runs fine, but sometimes, after running for many hours in fails to return from a call to a jpa repository.

Process Explorer shows minimal cpu/io activity.  Other threads in the application continue to access the database without issue.

I'm pretty much at a loss where to start looking for the problem here, any suggestions welcome.

My repository definition is:

```
@Repository
public interface TradeRepository extends JpaRepository<TradeDbo, Long>{ 
  ... 
  @Query("select t.tradeId from TradeDbo t where t.currencyPair.id = :currencyPairId") 
  HashBag<String> getTradeIdListByCurrencyPairId(@Param("currencyPairId") Long currencyPairId);
}
```

The invoking code is:

```
log.trace("Entering tradeRepository.getTradeIdListByCurrencyPairId");
Bag<String> tradeIdsInDb = tradeRepository.getTradeIdListByCurrencyPairId(currencyPairId);
log.trace("Back from tradeRepository.getTradeIdListByCurrencyPairId");
```

A normal log entry is:

```
2018-09-30 00:34:12,458 TRACE [TradesFetcher-Gdax] [CoinDbService.java:484] biz.ianw.coindatabase.services.data.CoinDbService - Entering tradeRepository.getTradeIdListByCurrencyPairId
2018-09-30 00:34:20,509 TRACE [TradesFetcher-Gdax] [CoinDbService.java:486] biz.ianw.coindatabase.services.data.CoinDbService - Back from tradeRepository.getTradeIdListByCurrencyPairId
```

But when it hangs I get something like:

```
2018-09-30 00:34:22,732 TRACE [TradesFetcher-Gdax] [CoinDbService.java:484] biz.ianw.coindatabase.services.data.CoinDbService - Entering tradeRepository.getTradeIdListByCurrencyPairId
2018-09-30 01:05:37,626 INFO  [coinLister-gdax] [CoinListerTask.java:170] biz.ianw.coindatabase.services.CoinListerTask - coinLister-gdax starting...
...
```

until such time as I break it (^C) and then I get:

```
2018-09-30 05:11:13,441 WARN  [TradesFetcher-Gdax] [ProxyConnection.java:161] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection - HikariPool-1 - Connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@57ee5254 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0)
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 16,604,912 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 16,610,693 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2088)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1992)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3413)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:471)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3115)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2344)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2739)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.PreparedStatementSpy.executeQuery(PreparedStatementSpy.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2168)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1931)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:938)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1489)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.getTradeIdListByCurrencyPairId(Unknown Source)
    at biz.ianw.coindatabase.services.data.CoinDbService.addLatestTradesGdax(CoinDbService.java:485)
    at biz.ianw.coindatabase.services.data.CoinDbService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$264af1e2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
...

2018-09-30 05:11:13,456 ERROR [TradesFetcher-Gdax] [Slf4jSpyLogDelegator.java:135] jdbc.audit - 918447. PreparedStatement.executeQuery() select tradedbo0_.trade_id as col_0_0_ from trade tradedbo0_ where tradedbo0_.currency_pair_id=21185892 

2018-09-30 05:11:13,472 ERROR [TradesFetcher-Gdax] [Slf4jSpyLogDelegator.java:154] jdbc.sqltiming - 918447. PreparedStatement.executeQuery() FAILED! select tradedbo0_.trade_id as col_0_0_ from trade tradedbo0_ where tradedbo0_.currency_pair_id=21185892 
 {FAILED after 16610724 msec}
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

The final lines, showing the execution of the prepared statement, and the stack trace at the time of the kill, are suggestive of some problem in the execution of the statement, but it's not clear to me if it's a bug or some resource depletion.

**Update**

Today's testing got an error in a different place, a save, after running for under 2 hours:

```
2018-10-01 11:40:33,458 INFO  [TradesFetcher-Gdax] [CoinDbService.java:504] biz.ianw.coindatabase.services.data.CoinDbService - Saving...
2018-10-01 17:28:11,066 INFO  [Thread-6] [Shutdown.java:12] biz.ianw.coindatabase.Shutdown - TradesFetcher-Gdax: shutdown hook started

log.info("Saving...");  
currencyPairRepository.save(currencyPairDboToProcess);
log.info("Save complete");
```

This testing also included the addition of a 60 second timeout, to no effect:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false, rollbackFor=Exception.class, timeout=60)
```

I've turned on log4jdbc options:

```
logging.level.jdbc.sqlonly=info
logging.level.jdbc.connection=info
```

and am running again to see what, if anything I can learn from that...

**Update**

Very little apparently.  Ran for 3 1/2 hours, hang in a different place:

```
03:35:44.208 INFO  [TradesFetcher-Gdax] [Slf4jSpyLogDelegator.java:228] jdbc.sqlonly - insert into trade (creation_date, last_modified_date, currency_pair_id, original_amount, price,
timestamp, trade_id, type, version, id) values ('10/02/2018 03:35:40.806', '10/02/2018 03:35:40.806',
21185896, '0.69562553', '133.33000000', 1521469001403, '2893530', 'BID', 0, 34504324)

06:03:46.589 INFO  [Thread-6] [Shutdown.java:12] biz.ianw.coindatabase.Shutdown - TradesFetcher-Gdax: shutdown hook started
```

Comment: Have you changed the default MySQL transaction isolation level?

Comment: @AdamSiemion I'm not sure how I would do that in spring jpa.  My procedure is annotated "@Transactional(readOnly=false, rollbackFor=Exception.class)" if that helps?

Comment: The connection between mysql and your application maybe get staled, as mysql closes its connections after a period of non-activity on a connection.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949/javatomcat-dying-database-connection) might help

Comment: @Bowie How long is this period?  The previous working queries took about 8 seconds.

Comment: @lan, I think the default value is 8 hours. I am not sure that the 'previous working queries' actually performed on the same connection. Maybe you should check the connection pool related configuration. For example: 'spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout' and 'spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query'.

Comment: @Bowie The HikariConfig connectionTimeout is set to 30000 (mS, I believe). test-query seems to be not recommended with mysql because jdbc4 has a better way of testing if a connection is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been caused by downlevel hikari and/or jdbc drivers in the Spring Boot package I was using.  Updating Hikari gave me a warning about jdbc being unable to check if a connection was still valid, and updating the drivers made that go away.  I've had no hangs in testing (yet...) since.